# Running HtmlService template through MathJax before sending out as an html email

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, html-email, mathjax

I have been using Google Apps Scripts recently to try and help out graders in an online class by creating a UI that allows them to enter grades directly to a spreadsheet and send off a feedback email to the student in one action.

Since this is a math class, I would like the graders to enter into the "comments" text input box of the UI strings like " $ \int_a^b f(x) dx $ ... " and have them be rendered by MathJax before being sent out as an email.

Currently,  this is what I do to go from html file to template to email:

```
  var email_template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('feedbackEmail');

  email_template.homeworkNum = homeworkNum;
  email_template.first = student.name.first;

  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var user = userEmail.substring(0, userEmail.indexOf('@'));
  email_template.grader = user;

  email_template.problems = grades.split(' ');
  email_template.problemComments = problemComments;
  email_template.comments = comments;

  var email_body = email_template.evaluate().getContent();
```

In particular, the comments and problemComments strings will contain LatexCode that I would like interpreted before sending the email body.   I would prefer not using embedded images since this would depend on external sources.

I figure that a major workaround is going to be necessary, but I was wondering if any body else has tried anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that MathJax runs client-side in your browser. Since Apps Script is executed server-side it wouldn't be possible to render the equations, nor would it be possible to save it in a form the email could display.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I was hoping that it would be possible to simulate a client side execution within the server where google app scripts is running.